# So much or too much

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I've got **so much/ too much** work to do to come to the beach. 
If "so much" is correct, so don't we use "too much"
Thank you so much

Comment: It's not clear all all what you're trying to say with that sentence.

Comment: @CookieMonster I guess they meant they can't go to the beach because they have many tasks to do.

Answer (score 2):

"**So much**" in this example is being used to denote that you have **a lot** of work to do, but it can also imply a **specified amount**.

For example:

> I can only do **so** much work.

This is the same meaning of the word but is being used to show that you have *a limit* to what you can do.

"**Too much**" in your example has a different meaning, not simply that you have a lot, but that the amount you have is **excessive**.

Consider *this* example:

> That is **too much** coffee for one person to drink.

This means that one person *cannot* drink that amount.

When used in *your example*:

> I have too much work to do.

This implies one of two meanings, either that (1) it is not possible to complete the amount of work you have; or, if said in answer to a question such as "*can you do something for me?*", that (2) the amount of work you have is does not allow you time to do this new task being asked of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can say either:

> I have so much work to do!

which is really an exclamation, or

> I have too much work to do.

Using **too** like this would generally be way of declining an invitation to do something else, indicating that your work prevents you from accepting it.

So, in your example, you have **too** much work to do to go the beach.

It's not correct to say: I have so much work to do to accept your invitation....

But you could use **so** if you rewrite the sentence to say:

> I have so much work to do that I cannot go to the beach.